# The figure corrupted after saved in the directory using saveas

Tags: matlab

I have 2 problems with the figure. First is: when the figure displayed in Matlab, it is like below:
[image]
But when I saved it in my directory using this code:

```
DirectoryPath ='C:\Users\Behzad\Desktop\Figures';
whereToStore=fullfile(DirectoryPath,['filename', '.png']);
saveas(gcf, whereToStore);
```

the saved figure is:
[image]

The Second problem is I want to ask if there is any way to reduce the font size of the axis number in the figure; And if there is any way to display x-axis numbers vertically.

Comment: How did you create the figure? Please read [mre]. It’s hard to know what happened there if we can’t reproduce it on our own computer.